# Base_link doubt

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS navigation stack and I'm have a doubt with a configuration parameter of costmap2d.

I have a differential drive which shaft it isn't the center of the robot. I don't know where I have to put the base_link: in the rotation point or in the geometric center of the robot.

Could anyone help me?

Thank's in advance

Kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10239/base_link-doubt/) by [Ane](https://answers.ros.org/users/684/ane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`base_link` (or `base_footprint` depending on your configuration) should go at the rotational center of the robot, i.e. the point about which the diff drive robot can spin-in-place. This assumes that `base_link` is the frame you will be using to command velocities relative to.

I don't know if this is actually explicitly stated anywhere, but it's how I've always configured move_base.

Note that you can always make another frame called "geometric_center" or something similar and publish a transform between that and `base_link` if you would prefer other transforms relative to the geometric center of the robot instead of the center of rotation.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-06-13**:
Good point on this never being documented. I added a note in this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF mentioning it.